# Code failure when I try to build project with gulp and uplift-js

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-uglify

I am geting to build my project with gulp and uglify-js but it fails and can’t build. And I can’t find what is wrong with this small code snippet.

**Function:**

```
function getOneSignalToken() {
    window.bridge.post('onesignaltoken', {},     (results, error) => {
         $('#onesignal_token').html(results.token);
    });
}
```

**Error**

```
events.js:160
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
```

Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (eval at  (/Users/erik/Desktop/Erik/code/nat5/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), :1545:18)
    at js_error (eval at  (/Users/erik/Desktop/Erik/code/nat5/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), :1553:11)
    at croak (eval at  (/Users/erik/Desktop/Erik/code/nat5/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), :2092:9)
    at token_error (eval at  (/Users/erik/Desktop/Erik/code/nat5/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), :2100:9)
    at unexpected (eval at  (/Users/erik/Desktop/Erik/code/nat5/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), :2106:9)
    at expr_atom (eval at  (/Users/erik/Desktop/Erik/code/nat5/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), :2633:9)
    at maybe_unary (eval at  (/Users/erik/Desktop/Erik/code/nat5/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), :2795:19)
    at expr_ops (eval at  (/Users/erik/Desktop/Erik/code/nat5/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), :2830:24)
    at maybe_conditional (eval at  (/Users/erik/Desktop/Erik/code/nat5/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1),:2835:20)
    at maybe_assign (eval at  (/Users/erik/Desktop/Erik/code/nat5/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), :2859:20)
    at maybe_assign (eval at  (/Users/erik/Desktop/Erik/code/nat5/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), :2867:32)
    at expression (eval at  (/Users/erik/Desktop/Erik/code/nat5/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), :2878:20)
    at expr_list (eval at  (/Users/erik/Desktop/Erik/code/nat5/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), :2644:24)
    at subscripts (eval at  (/Users/erik/Desktop/Erik/code/nat5/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), :2778:30)
    at subscripts (eval at  (/Users/erik/Desktop/Erik/code/nat5/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), :2755:20)
    at subscripts (eval at  (/Users/erik/Desktop/Erik/code/nat5/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), :2755:20)
Eriks-MacBook-Pro:nat5 erik$

Comment: Does your version of gulp and uglify-js support es2015?

Comment: If not then change (results, error) => to function(results, error) and try again

Comment: Add the error you are getting otherwise so we can help you debug

Comment: Where do I see the version? Also updated the question with the error log

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works now! Love it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting to pre es6/es2015 syntax

```
(results, error) => {...}
```

will become

```
function(results, error) {...}
```

To use gulp with new style es2015 see: https://markgoodyear.com/2015/06/using-es6-with-gulp/

And if you want to upgrade uglify-js to support es6 use the uglify-es npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-es

Answer (score 0):

As @peter sad.. this fixed the problem:

```
function getOneSignalToken() {
    window.bridge.post('onesignaltoken', {}, function(results, error){
         $('#onesignal_token').html(results.token);
    });
}
```